# Change Pin Image of MKMapView on specific zoom In-Out iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, swift4, mkannotationview

My Current MKMapView is:

[image]

But when I zoom in I want to change Pin Image to this:

[image]

and again zoom out change to default violet circle.

I just want to change Pin Image when user zoom In/Out MKMapView in iOS Swift 4.
Thanks In Advance!
Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. First of all you need to get information which pin/annotation display on you map.

Objective c

```
-(void)getAnotationsInVisibleMapRectangle
{
    NSSet *annotationSet = [myMapView annotationsInMapRect:myMapView.annotationVisibleRect];
    NSArray *annotationArray = [annotationSet allObjects]; 
}
```

Swift

```
extension MKMapView {
    func visibleAnnotations() -> [MKAnnotation] {
        return self.annotationsInMapRect(self.visibleMapRect).map { obj -> MKAnnotation in return obj as! MKAnnotation }
    }
}
```

Step 2. You will have delegate method will call on zoom in/out `regionDidChangeAnimated`. just call the as above function. And update the Your pin.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
            print("call on zoom and zoom out ")
            let aryData = mapView.visibleAnnotations()
            print(aryData[0].coordinate)
      //remove pin from this coordinate
       //And add new pin as you want
}
```

Here you can just find the pin. And remove old pin and add new pin as you want.

Comment: can you explain in detail

Comment: Have you got the pin detail?

Comment: yes definitely just tell me in which language you are work.

Comment: swift 4 @kalpesh

Comment: can you please provide me gtalk ID? so I can further explain it to you